# representations of a non-separable $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a non-separable $C^*$-algebra, can we deduce that all the representations of $A$ are infinie dimensional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Take a non-metrizable compact space $X$ so that $C(X)$ is non-separable, but it has lots of one-dimensional representations.

Comment: Do you think my answer works too?

Comment: How to check that $C(X)$ is non-separable?

Comment: @mathbeginner This is a standard result: If $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then $C(X)$ is separable iff $X$ is metrizable.

Comment: @Quantum, yes I think it works.  If $I$ is uncountable then $\mathbb C^{(I)}$ is not separable because the points in the uncountable set $\{\delta_i: i\in I\}$ are at distance 1 from each other.

Comment: @Ruy Thanks! +1

Comment: @QuantumSpace， Would you mind telling me which reference book has the proof of the "standard result"?

Comment: @mathbeginner Really, check any functional analysis book.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be an uncountable set and fix $j \in I$. Define

$$\pi: \mathbb{C}^{(I)} \to B(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}:  (\lambda_i)_{i \in I} \mapsto \lambda_j$$

Then $\pi$ is a one-dimensional representation of $A$. Moreover, $\mathbb{C}^{(I)}$ is non-separable because the set $\{\delta_i : i \in I\}$ of Dirac-functions satisfies $\| \delta_i - \delta_j\| = 1$ when $i \neq j$, and thus we can build an uncountable set of disjoint open balls, which shows that any dense set must be uncountable. (Credit goes to @Ruy for the above argument).

---

If you want something non-abelian simply take the direct sum with a non-abelian $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: I guess by $\mathbb{C}^{(I)}$ you mean $c_0(I)$?

Comment: @MaoWao Something like that. The elements are functions $I \to \mathbb{C}$ that are uniformly bounded or vanish on infinity, but I'm not entirely sure this is non-separable for sufficiently large $I$.

Comment: Is $\lambda_j$ the $j$-th coordinate of  $(\lambda_i)_{i\in I}$ ?  $\Bbb C^{(I)}$ may not be in-separable.

Comment: Yes, $\lambda_j$ is the $j$-th coordinate.